# Why is it possible in JavaScript to refer to arguments in a caller?

Tags: javascript

What mechanism permits a JavaScript function to refer to `arguments` from its caller by the name of the calling function and why is it still in the language?

I was looking up tail call optimization (or rather the lack thereof) in V8 and came across this post (https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=457)

Erik Corry's example is given below

```
function foo(x) {
  return bar(x + 1);
}

function bar(x) {
  return foo.arguments[0];
}

foo(1)
```

At first I thought maybe invoking a function sets its `arguments` field as some kind of weird global side effect, but it only appears to last for the duration of the call.

```
function foo(x) {
    return bar(x+1);
}

function bar(x) {
    return foo.arguments[0];
}

console.log(foo(1)); // prints '1'
console.log(foo.arguments); // prints 'null'
```

Why is this behavior in the language? Is it useful for anything besides backwards compatibility?

EDIT:

I am not asking about using `arguments` to refer to the pseudo-array of arguments in the current function body, e.g.

```
function variadic() {
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        console.log("%s-th item is %s", i, JSON.stringify(arguments[i]));
    }
}

variadic(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, []);
```

I am asking about using `somefunction.arguments` to refer to `arguments` of a caller.

Comment: In Javascript a function may be called with any number of arguments, no matter how many of them are listed.  JavaScript functions have a built-in object called the arguments object that supports this ability.

Comment: My mistake, I had a typo in my example. It should have said `foo.arguments`.

Comment: note that this behavior is gone in strict mode, and attempting to read a function's `.arguments` will throw an error  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode  (under "securing")

Comment: As [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/arguments) explains, it's useful for use in the case of **recursion**

Comment: I didn't down vote anyone. I added a clarifying example to my question.

Comment: @hindmost that's a terrible example (not to say that it does not work): for that functions must use `return`

Comment: @GregoryNisbet your second example has an infinite recursion.

Comment: [*"This feature has been removed from the Web standards. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped. Do not use it in old or new projects. Pages or Web apps using it may break at any time."*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/arguments).

Comment: *"Why is this behavior in the language?"* Might be better asked on https://esdiscuss.org/. It's unlikely anybody who worked on the language frequents Stack Overflow.

Comment: @zerkms Thanks for pointing that out. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be useful if you want to catch errors and compute them inside your own code, so you can clarify things to end user (or just debug) on an integrated output, or send those errors to server so you know there is a problem on your code. All this `caller` and `arguments` stuff can help on debugging the stack. It can also help on logging (again, debugging stuff), printing the name of the caller function (and possibly its arguments).
Or you can do an esoteric program that uses this information somehow usefully (maybe inside an object function).

The reason **why** it exists is that this is part of the language (I think *why* is not a good question here).

Answer (score -1):

You can pass the `arguments` variable to the called function:

```
function foo(x) {
    return bar(x+1, arguments);
}

function bar(x, foo_arguments) {
    return foo(foo_arguments[0]);
}
```

Or put that variable on a global variable:

```
var args = false;

function foo(x) {
    args = arguments;
    return bar(x+1);
}

function bar(x) {
    return foo(args[0]);
}
```

EDIT:

Or use the `caller` property of the function:

```
function foo(x) {
    return bar(x+1);
}

function bar(x) {
    return foo(bar.caller.arguments[0]);
}
```

But all of this has not too much sense to me. Can you clarify what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: If somebody downvotes, at least could let a comment of why.

Comment: i downvoted because this doesn't seem to have anything to do with the actual question of how `foo.arguments` is useful and why it exists